# many facebook like buttons on a page, asynchronously

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, facebook-like

I'm building a wall of people who've written messages on our site.  For each message, I want to include a Facebook Like button.  But Facebook's implementation is to include the script tag before building the fb:like tag.

```
 <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
      <fb:like href="http://example.com/MessageWall.aspx/Fan/222" 
            show_faces="false" width="250">
 </fb:like>
```

I tried this approach, but because I'm showing 121 people on the page at a time, the page performance is, shall we say, sub-par.  I can't believe that I have to include the script tag each time.

I'm trying now, to implement an asynchronous way of doing this.

I've tried this:

```
    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(e, s);
    }());

    var firstHalfOfLikeButton = '<fb:like href="http://example.com/MessageWall.aspx/Fan/';
    var secondHalfOfLikeButton = '" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" width="250"></fb:like>';
    var userId, divId;
    for (var x=0; x<listOfIdsOfActiveTiles.length; x++) {
        userId = listOfIdsOfActiveTiles[x][0];
        divId= listOfIdsOfActiveTiles[x][1];
        $("div#" + divId+ " .hbo-message").append(firstHalfOfLikeButton + userId + secondHalfOfLikeButton);
    }
```

I also tried to asynchronously attach the all.js to the fb-root like this BEFORE looping through and attaching the fb:like tag to each location.

```
 (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
     e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1';
         document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
 }());
```

I also tried looping through and creating the fb:like tag, and THEN attaching the all.js file.

Update:  In each instance, I can see the <fb:like... tag is successfully created, but the facebook all.js just never goes out and actually builds the button, like it does if you load it all up at first load.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,
Scott

### UPDATE

Returning to this page, way after the fact, but what I ended up doing was to dynamically build a like button for each person's image upon click of the item. So, my onclick code checks to see if it's not already there, and if not, builds it using the building blocks I have above.

This way, I don't have to create 121 like buttons upon page load. Instead, I create them on-demand.

You can see the finished project at [honeybunchesofoats.com](http://honeybunchesofoats.com)

Comment: Scott, could you elaborate your final solution? I want to do the same thing but didn't understand how you change the fb-like url for each itme? Didn't see the attachment to each click event

Answer (score 1):

You only need to include the facebook script once, not once for each like button..  It will then search through the page for all xfbml elements.

Comment: do I add it before or after I've added the fb:like elements?  Because I've tried both, and the buttons are not created.  If I look in the page source, I see what should be a Like button, but it just never got initialized or something.

Comment: Include it once using the asynchronous method. There is a little demo here of someone who wanted to do exactly the same thing, which is working perfectly.

http://hillarsaare.com/projects/facebook/multi-like/